# NSDateFormatter issue in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I'm using a NSDateFormatter to get the Date in a special Format, what I can then add as a param to my Webservice API.

But since the new iOS8 Release I've a problem.

This is my Dateformatter:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYYMMddhhmm"];
NSString *dateStr = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"Set Update to Date: %@",dateStr);
```

The result what I get is:

```
Set Update to Date: 2015030909:31
```

But WHY the `:` is between the hour and mins? Is this a BUG?

PS: This code always worked before.

Comment: I tried the same code. The result I got is `Set Update to Date: 201503090214`. The code works good

Comment: When I'm using `[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYYMMddHHmm"]` I get the correct result.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907011/nsdateformatter-issue-with-date-format-in-ios-8