# NSDateFormatter behaves differently on iOS 8 and iOS 7

Tags: ios7, ios8, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am getting `NSDate` from `NSSting` by using the `NSDateFormatter`. I am using following code

```
NSDate * GetDatefromFormat(NSString *strDate, NSString *format )
{
        if(!format || !strDate) return nil;
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat: format];
        return [formatter dateFromString:strDate];
}
```

The input to this function is are two NSString values like `"2015-03-04T03:56:38+00:00"` and the format is `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"`.

I was working on `iOS 8` and it was working totally fine but then i have tested my app on `iOS 7` and it gives me nil. 
Actually this line `[formatter dateFromString:strDate];` returns me nil.

Any idea why its working on `iOS 8` and not on `iOS 7`?
How can i make it work on all iOS versions?

Comment: Did you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907011/nsdateformatter-issue-with-date-format-in-ios-8)?